# How to access the execution context from a Cucumber step definition

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Can one access the cucumber executor context from a step definition to - for example - determine if the current step definition is the last entry of a scenario?

Comment: Why would you want that?
Try passing the Scenario object in your tearDown() method and see if there is a valuable information for you there.

Comment: I'm wondering whether it is possible to add a list of then's that add their validation condition to a list of checks, only invoke an API at the last step and run all defined checks on the result. Also, some then's could be asynchronous calls and I was thinking of checking all futures on the last one

Comment: It sounds like you will have some dependencies between scenarios, am I right?

Comment: That's the point, I'd like to avoid dependencies: step definition adds its own condition and finally could do and if-last-then-process-all-in-list. If it's alone it reduces to itself, otherwise it collects all previous as well. Although errors of other steps would appear in this one...

Comment: As I know, cucumber encourages you to write independent scenarios and not doing anything for previous one. In you case, I would write some tests and do all the needed checks/validations after each scenario and not taking care if a step is last or whatever.